# Sliced Pie in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I am using high charts and it is working amazingly as usual.

But what I want to achieve is, I want all slices to be sliced (Gaps in between all the slices of pie). One way by which I can do that is:

```
borderWidth:0,
borderColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0)"
```

But this is not working, is there any approach by which I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do so by using:

```
sliced: true,
```

See [example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/oebrmqu8/)

As per @Halvor's comment updated [fiddle with distance](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/oebrmqu8/1/) using slicedOffset: 5

Comment: Aah nice, by any chance can i control the sliced distance?